# Not able to connect to the slot in qt

Tags: c++, qt5

Here i am adding part of my code, i have my main function and MainWindow class

Basically my init() function should be triggered in order to fill my display_images queue in timercalldisplay() function so i am calling it from my main

But i am not able to get in to timercalldisplay() calling it through SLOT and init() is getting executed

Can anybody say what mistake i was doing

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    void init();

    QTimer *timer;

public slots:
    void timercalldisplay();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

};
```

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    w.init();

    return a.exec();
}
```

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timercalldisplay()));
    timer->start(500);

}

void MainWindow::timercalldisplay()
{
    qDebug() << display_images.size();                        //not reaching here
    while(display_images.size())
    {
        Mat img = display_images.front();
        QPixmap pixmap;
        QImage qimg(img.data, img.cols, img.rows, img.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
        pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(qimg.rgbSwapped());
        ui->label->setPixmap(pixmap);
        ui->label->setScaledContents(true);
        ui->label->show();
        QThread::currentThread()->msleep(1000);
        qApp->processEvents();
        display_images.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Advice: Stop using the obsolete, string based, `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros. Instead use the modern function-pointer based, compile time checked, syntax.

Comment: Common mistakes: missing `Q_OBJECT` macro when defining `MainWindow` class. `timercalldisplay` is not declared as slot, respective file is not pass to moc tool.

Comment: 1) change to `timer = new QTimer(this);` and 2) `connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWindow::timercalldisplay);`

Comment: @MarekR thankyou for the response.... I have added my MainWindow class i have added Q_OBJECT macro and timercalldisplay is declared as slot it is still same.

Comment: check qdebug log it should say why it failed to connect.

Comment: is your header containing `MainWindow` properly listed in `*.pro` or `CMakeLists.txt` file?

Answer (score 1):

```
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timercalldisplay()));
```

take the () out of the connect like
fixed

```
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWindow::timercalldisplay);
```

Also in you constructor change

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
```

to

```
timer = new QTimer(this);
```

Update based on new issue

Comment: In Qt5 there is a more safe way to connect a signal to a slot: `connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWindow::timercalldisplay)`. More safe because you'll get compile time error if make a typo (signal/slot does not exist, signatures are not compatible, etc).

Comment: @nicolai thankyou.... tried the same way but did not enter into slot

Comment: @Rahul, ok this means that the problem is somewhere else. How did you decide that the slot haven't been called? You didn't see see any output, did you? What build system do you use, cmake or qmake? Can you share the project build file (CMakeLists.txt or project_name.pro)? The only thing that comes to my mind that debug output might be disabled in your build file...

Comment: 1) I have used qDebug() << display_images.size(); statement to print the size of buffer. So when i run it didn't print the size.
2) I am using qmake.
3) It is working when i remove my while loop in timercalldisplay().

Comment: If you take the while loop out does the qDebug print out the size of the display_images?